# Едит в делфи

Tags: delphi

Как установить курсор в скрытый едит на делфи? Так, чтобы данные с клавиатуры всегда вводились в этот едит. 
Допустим у меня два окна программы. Также текстовый файлик с комбинацией чисел, я ввожу данные с клавиатуры они записываются в скрытий едит. После ввода я нажимаю ентер, если введенные данные едита и файлика одинаковы, открыть новое окно. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Курсор в скрытое поле ввода никак не установить. Можно установить обработчик onkeypress для родительской формы, в котором и будет записываться итоговая строка.

```
var ResultStr = '';
procedure Form1.Form1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; key: char);
begin
 ResultStr:= ResultStr + key;
end;
```

Или что-то в этом роде.

Answer (score 1):

Можно его (Edit) не скрывать, а поместить под другим компонентом, например Panel, тогда на него можно установить курсор (SetFocus) и символы будут вводиться в него.

Answer (score 0):

[@Programer](/users/1709/programer), а чем скрытый эдит отличается от обычного? Выставляете табуляцию на него(окно ввода), и запрещаете смену окна ввода, по средствам отлавливания сообщений от ОС, или задаете запрет за счет вызова функций Win32 API, если это возможно.